# TypeError: can't pickle weakref objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pickle

I am trying to `pickle.dump()` an object with a `model` property that stores a TensorFlow model.
This is the minimum code to reproduce my error (at least on my machine, macOS Big Sur 11.4 with Anaconda Python 3.6 enviroment and TensorFlow 2.3.1).

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle as pkl

class OBJ():
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

save_location = 'your save location here'
pkl.dump(OBJ(), save_location)
```

On run time this exception is thrown

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't pickle weakref objects
```

Reading online forums I realised that this error has something to do with the fact that there are some objects (like TensorFlow models) that cannot be pickled.
Does anybody know a method to pickle an "unpickable" object? What makes these object specials, so that they can't be pickled?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use tensorflow built in model saving functionality? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64340861/14290681) answer your query ?

Comment: @TFer2 i don't want to use the builtin saving functionality because that `OBJ` has also his own properties and methods, i want to save them with the tf model.

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68758041/5127304). It may help you if you wanna save tf models!