# pickling weakref in python while using LSTM algorithm

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

im wokring with LSTM algorithm for time series forecasting. to implement it to a web application i need to pickle my lstm model, while pickling the model its showing cannot pickle weakref object.

this is my lstm  model and i cannot able to pickle this model.

```
  model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)))
    model.add(LSTM(units=50))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=15, batch_size=25, verbose=2)
    model.summary()

import pickle
pickle.dump(model, open('model.pkl','wb'))
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-262afc454dac> in <module>
----> 1 pickle.dump(model, open('model.pkl','wb'))

TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object
```

hope someone will help me with this

Comment: Currently tensorflow supports the model can be saved in two different file formats (`SavedModel` and `HDF5`). The TensorFlow `SavedModel` format is the default file format in `TF2.x`. However, models can be saved in `HDF5` format in `TF1.x`.Thanks!

Comment: Your issue can resolved by following solutions discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64320839/getting-typeerror-cant-pickle-thread-rlock-objects/64340861#64340861).Thanks!